# How do I properly implement Biblatex with the Biber backend in Texmaker?

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texmaker, biber

I believe I have everything configured correctly (having looked at other questions). I have replaced `bibtex %` with `biber %` in the Commands and I have selected PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex (x2) + View Pdf.  Minimal working example as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Example.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{Cocks2011} liked to play in the snow. The snow was rather cold \citep{Cocks2011}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The example bilbliography:

```
@article{Cocks2011,
author = {Cocks, L. Robin M. and Torsvik, Trond H.},
doi = {10.1016/j.earscirev.2011.01.007},
issn = {00128252},
journal = {Earth-Science Reviews},
keywords = {Laurentia,Palaeozoic,palaeogeography},
number = {1-2},
pages = {1--51},
publisher = {Elsevier B.V.},
title = {{The Palaeozoic geography of Laurentia and western Laurussia: A stable craton with mobile margins}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S001282521100016X},
volume = {106},
year = {2011}
}
```

Running biber then Quick Build produces the following error:

```
 ! Package keyval Error: uniqueprimaryauthor undefined.See the keyval package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ... dateabbrev=false}
```

Comment: I neglected to mention that I am using the latest version of Miktex (v2.9)

Comment: This pretty much looks like a version mismatch between `biblatex`/Biber and `biblatex-apa` to me. Make sure to update all packages by running the Update Manager (in both Admin and User mode) twice.

Comment: Just for people getting here by some sort of search function: Refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on running Biber in TeXmaker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a a version mismatch between `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex`/Biber that has since been resolved by the OP (see comment below Bernard's answer).

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. For me there's just a small problem with  your code: the `apa` style requires a `\DeclareLanguageMapping`  declaration. Also, you should  load `csquotes`. So add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

[image]

*Edit* (20/02/2019):
 As indicated by @moewe's comment below, `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is now automatic in recent versions of `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: I have added those three lines but the uniqueprimaryauthor error remains the same.

Comment: With only the code and bibliography you posted?

Comment: Also which versions of `biber` and `biblatex` do you use?

Comment: I took on board the advice by @moewe to update everything and it is all working now. Thanks very much Bernard and moewe

Comment: In recent versions of `biblatex-apa` the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` will be applied automatically, so there is no need for a manual mapping any more.

Comment: @moewe: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information! I've edited my answer accordingly, to be sure anyone who reads the answer sees it.